# How to send emails from spring application using gmail?

Tags: java, spring, email, smtp, gmail

I am working on a spring (annotation based) application.

One of the page asks user to provide their contact details and message. Once this page is submitted, I want these details to be sent by email to my company ID.

Can someone provide sample example/code which I can use to achieve this functionality? I want to use gmail smpt server.

Comment: You might be looking at something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11673221/attach-the-uploaded-file-as-an-email/11673520#comment15757618_11673520

Comment: Special tutorial to do this: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/07/java-mail-spring-gmail-smtp.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look here:
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/mail.html

Create a JavaMailSenderImpl bean with the SMTP data from GMail and register it into the application context.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like what you want is Java Mail...

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html

This will allow you to send mail through the gmail smtp server...

smtp.gmail.com (use authentication)

Use Authentication: Yes

Port for TLS/STARTTLS: 587

Port for SSL: 465

According to http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=13287

Answer (score 1):

You can either use [JavaMail](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html) (SMTP) or [Google API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/#oauth_access_to_imap_and_smtp).

JavaMail is more straightfoward, but use SMTP communication. Google API is a bit longer to get it on, but is web based (REST)